# Error in Magento 2 when trying to deploy

Tags: magento2, static-content, less

I have this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in
>   vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php
>   on line 64

in Magento 2 when I try do use this command to clear the cached files:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Does anyone else have this problem?

Later Edit:
I want to regenerate the static content, it was a bad wording before.
I am using Magento 2.0.2 and I used the downloaded file from magento.com

Comment: But `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` is not the right command to clear cache files. It creates/regenerates the static content.  Also, can you specify what version of Magento2, and  how did you deploy? via git, composer create project or downloaded a zip from magento.com?

Answer (score 2):

You php do not have `intl` extension. You can verify it by run `php -i`.

In many cases this problem appear when you have different php version/configurations for apache and cli. For example if use install MAMP on MacOsX that you will have different version. To use php in this case you need specify full path to php like `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php`

To change it you need to do  folowing steps:

Edit  `~/.bash_profile` and add

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x/bin:$PATH
```

where `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x` should be patch to your latest wersion

In Terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`

In Terminal, type in `which php` and look for the updated patch. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you do not have php's intl extension. Please install this according to your OS and PHP Version. Here are instructions for [Ubuntu](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html) and [Centos](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html).

How did you install Magento 2? via CLI or Web?