# Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, locale, static-content, deploy

when I run this command

`static-content:deploy`

then I got the below error

> "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Locale' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/magento2_1/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php".

can you please help me how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: i can give you reference links Kartik https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2316, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119917/run-grunt-deploy-task-fatal-error-class-locale-not-found, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95991/local-installation-of-magento-2-doest-not-generate-files-in-the-pub-static-folde

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local installation of Magento 2 doest not generate files in the pub/static folder](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95991/local-installation-of-magento-2-doest-not-generate-files-in-the-pub-static-folde)

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs when you do not have **php's intl extension**.

For futher info. you can chk

1. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2316
2. [Run Grunt deploy task -> Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119917/run-grunt-deploy-task-fatal-error-class-locale-not-found)
3. [Error in Magento 2 when trying to deploy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108606/error-in-magento-2-when-trying-to-deploy)

Answer (score 2):

The sollution I found was to run xampp's shell and there write the code. Otherwise, on command prompt ( Windows ) it would give me the same error.