# Magento 2.4 Installation Issue on localhost Xampp

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.0

I am trying to install M2.4 on my local machine, But getting error list, I have install elastic search and when i run below command in CMD then getting error list. Please check attached screenshot.

Command Running in CMD:

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/faksouq24" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="faksouq24" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="testing@gmail.ae" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"

Error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in C:\xampp72\htdocs\faksouq24\vendor\magento\framework
Locale\Bundle\DataBundle.php:64

Please help me regarding about this issue, why i am getting this error ?

Thanks & Regards

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if php_intl extension is enabled from your php.ini file. If it isn't, than enable it and restart apache. Hopefully than you can install magento with the command line.

Comment: php_intl is already enabled.

Comment: try to run the same command from xampp's shell rather than git bash or windows cmd. See this for reference
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164412/85210

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `php's intl extension` is missing. Please enable it in php.ini and restart apache.

If you have any other issues, try this tutorial. It explain in detail how to fix any issues when installing Magento 2.4 on Localhost

https://magentip.com/install-magento-2-on-localhost-xampp-elasticsearch/